# Should I prune a redwood tree suckers?

Tags: trees

I have 30 year old redwoods.  One keeps sprouting a lot of suckers at ground level. All have suffered from drought in California. I have added water to help with this.  Should I prune the suckers or let them grow into a bush/tree?

Comment: a picture would help

Comment: Coast redwoods often have stump sprouts after being cut or burned. I don't think they sprout when they are healthy. If the tree is in fact ill or damaged, you might let the sprouts replace it.